# AngularJS infinite loop with # at end of url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-loop

I have:

```
$routeProvider.when('/here/:id',{
   templateUrl: '/this'
   , controller: 'that'   
})
```

and I am using:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

With AngularJS 1.2.27

If I browse to:

```
/here/1234#
```

angular goes into an infinite loop.  How do I prevent this?
I don't need the # at the end, but I do need to prevent the infinite loop.
Thanks!

[edit]
It seems this happens with other angularjs apps as well, I tried a random example here (see the console): http://hike.io/discover#

Comment: did you try to check $locationProvider.hashPrefix property?

Comment: Have you configured your server to work with html5mode?

Comment: @shershen I tried to check hashPrefix, but when I inject $locationProvider other than in the config I get an injector error?